# How can I only show a widget prior to a specific date?

Tags: widgets, date

I can't find a solution for this anywhere, so help is highly appreciated!

The problem is, that my Dropbox account is losing aboz 48 GB's, so I had to remove my podcast episodes from there... because there are too many posts to change now, I want to add a note in the left sidebar. This note should only be seen on posts prior to August 22nd. Where I will tell the people on how to download now, if they tried to download using the dropbox link.

I tried widget changer, dynamic widgets and some other plugins, but none of those did the trick. Maybe you have an idea. I hope I made clear what I meant, if not please ask if something is unclear.

again, any help would be highly appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to do this through the WordPress admin and not edit your sidebar.php so here is a possible solution.

First, find out what the timestamp of August 22 was at http://www.epochconverter.com. Based on GMT time I got "1408665600"

Install the Widget Logic Plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/

Add a widget to your left sidebar. If you wanted it to be a message then a text widget might work best.

In the widget logic box of the widget, try something like the below:

`get_the_date('U') <= "1408665600"`

It's saying to show the widget if the Unix timestamp of the post's publish date is less (earlier) than or equal to the Unix timestamp of August 22, 2014.

If your widget area is shared over multiple pages and/or post types then you can also restrict it to only show when the above matches as well as the post type, something like:

`get_post_type() == 'post' && get_the_date('U') <= "1408665600"`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

My other answer was deleted :( don't really get why, tried to edit, but it remained deleted. so here's again. hopefully it stays, as the problem still exists.

it doesn't work, well not like I wanted to... because the message shows up on every page, even on the starting part of the blog http://wrestling-talk.de/wordpress

I used get_the_date('U') <= "1408665600" but then the post won't show up for the podcast sites

then I tried get_post_type() == 'podcast' && get_the_date('U') <= "1408665600" but the message shows up on the staring page aswell, what can I do?

Comment: Sorry I can't help, but if the other answer didn't solve your problem you should untick it. Your other answer probably got deleted because it was a comment on the other answer and not an answer in itself; as the question asker you can add a comment to the other answer or edit clarifications and follow-up into your question.